# How to show this .php file inside this modal div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Now when I click the link it goes to link. works fine. But how can I show posts.php  inside the div(modal) below.

I dont want to leave index.php . If it was a normal .php file I would simply inlcude and it would appear in the modal.

Here simple include does not work cause I  need to pass the id in posts.php for getting the exact post.

what should I do ?

index.php

```html
<li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="posts.php?id=<?=$post_id?>"  >show post</a></li>





<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Post</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
  <div >
          
          
          
          
          // I need  show posts.php  inside here
  
  
 
          
          
  
  </div>
  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

posts.php

```html
<?php 
include("connect.php");


 
$post_id = $_GET['id'];

$get_post = " SELECT * FROM `posts` where post_id='$post_id' ";

$run_post = mysql_query($get_post);
 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_post)){
 
 
  $post_title = $row['post_title'];
  
  $post_image = $row['post_image'];
  
 }

?>


<p> <?php echo $post_title;?></p>

<img  src="images/<?php echo $post_image;?>" />
```

Comment: `include` statement is much like moving the code away for convenience. So in included piece of code, you will have whatever variables you set before the `include` statement. Therefore you should define your `$products` in your `index.php` before including `posts.php`, and it will be available in `posts.php`. Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

You basically have three choices here:

### [`include`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[`require`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

You can use the keywords `include` or `require` to tell PHP to basically run the contents of another PHP file in the current file, like so:

```
<?php

$foo = "bar";

include "othercode.php"; //or alternatively: require "othercode.php";

echo "$foo + $variableinothercode";
?>
```

The difference between `include` and `require` is that `require` will throw a critical error if the file could not be found, while `include` will only throw a warning.

---

### iFrame

I wouldn't recommend this option; however it *is* an option so I'll include it anyway;

You could simply replace the `<div>` tags with an `<iframe>` with it's `src` attribute set to the location of the file, like so:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/othercode.php"></iframe>
```

---

### Copy/cut the code into the file

There's always the option of making the other file redundant by copying or cutting the contents of the file into the new file, however this should only be done if the file is not being included or used anywhere else as it will break those scripts; a simple `include` or `require` will suffice and be infinitely cleaner.